# A question regarding central limit theorem

Tags: probability

A professor knows that a grade of a student is a random variable with an average of 75, and variance of 75.

$E(X) = 75$, $V(X) = 25$
How many students need to be tested, in order to guarantee with a probability of at least $0.9$, that the average of test grade will be at the distance of 5 points from 75.

I first said this:

$$X \sim N\left(75, \frac{25}{n}\right)$$

So i tried to calculate the area between 70 and 80 to be at least 0.9, hence:

$$\phi\left(\frac{80-75}{\sqrt{\frac{25}{n}}}\right) - \phi\left(\frac{70-75}{\sqrt{\frac{25}{n}}}\right) \ge0.9$$

This didn't give me the right answer, can someone please explain why? and what is the way to go?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you add what value you got and what value you were expecting? Sometimes textbooks contain mistakes.

Comment: The value I'm expecting is 3

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of the Normal cumulative distribution function evaluated at 0.95 is 1.6449.

You need $1.6449\sqrt{(25/n)} \le 5$. This is false for n = 2 and true for n = 3. So n = 3 is the answer.